# Awesome WM not working with google-chrome

Tags: google-chrome, awesome, tiling

When I start google-chrome, everything appears to be fine, but when I attempt to change the current layout, the browser windows do not respond correctly. It almost seems as if there was an attempt to lay them out again, but the windows do not repaint.. if I attempt to change the layout again, the effects of the previous attempt keep piling on top of each other...

If anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Pls try to install **compton**, and run it:

$> compton --backend glx --paint-on-overlay --glx-no-stencil --vsync opengl-swc --unredir-if-possible